# How to show loading animation and avoid any user interaction till next activity is loaded?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my android app,

ActivityA ---> calls Service.java -----> calls ActivityB.

Service.java makes a web url call to JSON web services and everything is working fine as expected. 
Now I would like to show the loading animation in ActivityA until the code return values and take the user to ActivityB.

Questions
1) I went through Stack over flow and all of them answered to use BroadCastReceiver.

In Service.java , I do this

```
public Service {

   public String someMethod(){
       if(intent != null){
           Intent intent = new Intent("someAction");
           intent.putExtra("ABC", something);
           Context.sendBroadCast(intent);

           //Talk to JSON web services server
       }
   }
}
```

In ActivityA.java

```
public class ActivityA {

   public view onCreate(){
       //call Service.java
   }

   public static class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver(){
       public onReceive(){
           //
       }
   }
}
```

1) Earlier the Service.java returns to ActivityB.java, but now it returns to ActivityA.java
2) How does Service.java send the status of progress when I use sendBroadCast( ). I don't see anything like constantly sending the progress.
3) How else I can do this loading animation work in ActivityA? Please help.

PS: I have posted the code from what I remember. I will post the exact once I get home. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are asking for you can simply show ProgressDialog or any custom dialog with flag:

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Once you receive feedback from your service in your receiver of ActivityA you want to dismiss the dialog and send new intent to open ActivityB

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    public view onCreate(){
        //call Service.java
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    public static class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver(){
        public onReceive(){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // open ActivityB , append params
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to show approximate progress li 25/50/75/100 % then from your service you want to pass some integer which will be used in receiver in ActivityA to set progress at your ProgressDialog. Once it reaches 100 you will again need to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: But I don't want to show the progress the moment ActivityA is loaded. I want to show it after has made a choice in ActivityA. I think I will use onActionItemChangeListener( ).

Comment: well I have just appended that code after you call Service.java as I assume you want show progress when you launch Service. But in real scenario that piece of code will be likely at different place.